# Symfony issue with container.php

Tags: php, symfony, preg-replace

I am having an issue when I try to access my app using symfony3. Everything goes well until I get to request.php and the following static function is called from container.php

```
public static function underscore($id)
{
    return strtolower(preg_replace(array('/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/', '/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/'), array('\\1_\\2', '\\1_\\2'), str_replace('_', '.', $id)));
}
```

I did some testing and it seems to be an issue with preg_replace in general. I've tried recompiling php, creating a new vagrant machine, but the issue persists.

Is there a reason why preg_replace would be returning a null value despite having a valid regex expression?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's your question? You haven't told us what's actually going on.

Comment: edited for clarity.

Comment: How did you know that `preg_replace` returns `null`? Did you get a warning with it?

Comment: What's the value of `$id`? And what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I got a warning with '' with the string underscore is supposed to return. I then tried to skip the function all together and echo the result back, which returned null. $id is the name of a class. This is not my code, it's part of symfony itself.

Comment: the function takes different symfony classes and returns the name with an underscore. Example would be `$id="SensioBundle"` would return `Sensio_Bundle`

Comment: So what's the value of $id that is failing?

Comment: What's the error message? Can we see how have you debugged that code? (with `var_dump` and all)

Comment: `preg_replace` returns NULL only if there's an error. If there is one use `preg_last_error` to get the exact error message.

Comment: If it's a part of Symfony - please specify namespace of this class.
Also please post value of $id, as Jon Stirling asked. Probably name of that class (stored in $id) has some strange characters.